# Manual WCF and ChannelFactory

Tags: wcf, channelfactory

I am just getting started with WCF and am using an older article posted by Miguel A. Castro called [WCF the Manual Way](http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/39837). In the article he mentions using the ChannelFactory to create a service proxy.  In the article, he shows this code to create the proxy :

```
IProductAdmin productAdminChannel = new ChannelFactory<IProductAdmin>().CreateChannel();
```

When I try using that code with the endpoints configured in the web.config, I keep getting errors about this endpoint being null. Obvioulsy it works if I specify the name of the endpoint on the ChannelFactory constructor, but that doesn't seem to be the best option for re-usability.  But it also seems to work if I do this :

```
IProductAdmin productAdminChannel = new ChannelFactory<IProductAdmin>("*").CreateChannel();
```

Is this just a change in how the ChannelFactory class works (since the article is almost 2 years old)?  What is the "best practice" for creating WCF Service Proxies and re-usability?

Comment: Can you **show us** your web.config?? Does it have an endpoint inside the <client> section that references the **IProductAdmin** interface?? Your approach seems okay as far a I can tell from your code...

Comment: If you haven't already - you must also watch the DNR TV show with Miguel Castro called "Extreme WCF" - highly recommended! http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=122

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't my ChannelFactory see my endpoint configuration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426041/why-doesnt-my-channelfactory-see-my-endpoint-configuration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak for the original article, but maybe it's just an oversight by the author? As far as I know, the 2nd listing in your post has always been the way to create the channel using the config file. Passing a * will use the default/first configuration for the channel type in the file. You can also pass a specific name instead of a * in the case that you have multiple named configs for the same type.

I have been using the ("*") route for several years now, and it's a good way to go if you are only going to have one endpoint per type.

Comment: Is there any documentation on this?